# Vim as Visual Studio IDE

Tags: vim

I have spent lot of time  doing research on VIM. I am Windows guy since last 6 yrs and was using VS.
Now started working on Linux. I want to make VIM as close as possible to VS.
I want features like
Project Navigation
Files in Different Tabs
Search in Project
AutoCompletion

I have found plugins for the above requirements
Project Pligin
MiniExplore
Taglist
OmniComplete

I am not able to correctly set vimrc script.
When I try to open file from Project it gets open in different tabs.I want to get it open in different buffers.
Also when I want to close file in buffer , complete window gets closed.
Open taglist and project window makes all mess.

Has any one done settings with these plugin..
Could  you guys please post your vimrc files??
It will save lot of time for newbies like me..

Comment: What you are asking is an abomination. :-)

Comment: If you dont want to help let it be. But pleae dont make stupid comments.
I really dont know what you are taking about...

Comment: I suggest you get yourself a sense of humor.  That's what the ":-)" at the end of the message means.

Comment: paxdiablo, are you here to make people laugh or help them?

Comment: the two are not mutually exclusive, archmage.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Vim is a very different tool than Visual Studio. Plugins may help you get certain bits of functionality you desire, but do not expect them to work exactly like VS, work well together, or even work at all.

If you are looking for a programming environment more like Visual Studio, there are many good graphical IDE's you can use such as NetBeans, Eclipse, Code::Blocks, KDevelop, Anjuta, etc. Some of these tools are, IMHO, better heavyweight IDE's than Visual Studio, and all are available on Linux for free.

You should either learn to use Vim the way it was built to be used, or find a different tool that suits you better. Shoehorning Vim into a surrogate for Visual Studio will probably cause you more pain than it's worth.

Comment: Actually, I used NetBeans with the jVi plugin for a long time until I got so fed up with NetBeans crashing, that I'm back to using straight Vim.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer that actually understood the question.

Answer (score 17):

Yes it's different to VS, but that doesn't mean it can't be used in the same way. It's just not as easy to do it :)

Personally I go the other way and use [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) to get VS to behave like VIM. But I'm not in the same situation as the author of this question.

Why not have a dig through some [uploaded vimrc files on dotfiles.org](http://dotfiles.org/search?q=vimrc)?

Comment: Anyone looking at this now should look check out VsVim free plugin for VS http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329

Comment: @Boushley VsVim is half-baked and doesn't have anywhere near the level of functionality as VIM. If you were to go down the VS plugin route you're _much_ better off with ViEmu.

Comment: @OJ I'm definitely with you, none of these plugins is really as good as Vim itself. However for some people in some situations a plugin is the way to go. I've had a pretty good time with VsVim, it's being actively developed and keeps getting better. Are there specific things that ViEmu does better?

Comment: @Boushley Yeah mate. First of all the command coverage in VsVim isn't near the level of ViEmu, nor does it have the polish. The perf of quite a few of the commands is worse as well. Simple usage is ok, but if you're an intermediate VIMmer then you'll get frustrated pretty quickly with VsVim. ViEmu isn't perfect though, there are still gaps. Nothing beats the real VIM :)

Comment: @OJ Totally agree. I've just been so turned off by most plugins I don't come to expect much more than the basic kay mappings.

Comment: @OJ, as much as I like to agree with you that the plugin is half-baked or whatnot, [100+ reviews](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329/) on plugin page state otherwise. People who are actually using vim on *nix and this plugin with VS seem pretty much satisfied!

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following script, Trinity.
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2347
It will require 3 more scripts, and Vim will look like an IDE.
The TagList at left, a file exporer (NERDTree) at right, and Source Explorer at bottom.

Also, you can find some very useful blog entries at
http://kevin-berridge.blogspot.com/search/label/vim
The author, Kevin, explains how to compile solutions form inside Vim. He also shows interfacing and jumping between them which is very useful too.

Furhermore, there is the script vim-visual-studio which can be found at
http://code.google.com/p/vim-visual-studio/
This script is using Python extension. I have Python 2.5 installed in Windows. I am using Gvim 7.2 which is compiled with Python 2.4. So, I have replaced the executables of Gvim as explained here:
http://www.gooli.org/blog/gvim-72-with-python-2526-support-windows-binaries/
So, Gvim became compatible with Python 2.5 and raised no problems. Also, a menu entry "Visual Studio" has appeared as expected. It connects to Visual Studio itself, and it works perfectly. It does not just compiles a file, it can compile a solution containing more than one project as in Visual Studio. You can even use the Vim's 'quickfix' feature. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to have vim as the front end, try [Eclim](http://eclim.sourceforge.net). It uses Eclipse as a backend daemon for code completion and project management, and vim as the interface.

If you only like vim because of the vi key bindings, but want it to be more IDE like, you could try the latest [MonoDevelop](http://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2008/10/14/vi_modes_monodevelop) that has it built in.

Comment: I think you need to re-read his question. It seems he wants the opposite of what you are suggesting. He wants Vim to behave more like Visual Studio. Not the other way around.

Comment: I did read his question and answered that with a pointer to Eclim. The mention of MonoDevelop was just an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

These plugins used to exist long before vim had tabs. I'd be quite surprised there isn't a way to tune these plugins to split windows instead of opening tabs.
Now I can't help you much as I don't use these specific plugins but other ones. You should look at their help (:h project, :h taglist, etc)

PS: in vim terminology (it will help you browse the help files), what you call "buffer" is actually called "window", while a "buffer" is just the text you are working on, it may be associated to a file, or not. For a given buffer, there may be no or several window displaying parts of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

you can give a try to eXvim 
http://code.google.com/p/exvim/